# Remove/Delete particular cache

Tags: android, android-glide

There I am currently working on a user based apps like friends app
it simply shows the list of users with their avatar and caching images using this wonderful library. But problem occurs when
the URL of a particular user's avatar changes and there are two different avatar images save in cache directory of app.

There is no need of more than one avatar pic or single user.
In long run it will full with these garbage caches of different user's pervious avatars.
The need is to only cache single avatar of user
when URL changes remove previous one cache and cache updated avatar

**Glide Version: 4.7.1**

[image]
there are two different cache files of a single user
there is no need of previous one!

Please Guide this is serious hurdle.

**Please Note that URLs of avatar are dynamic only identifier will be user phone_number**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way-

```
public class GlideIdWithModifiedTime extends GlideUrl {

    private String mKey;

    public GlideIdWithModifiedTime(String url,String id, String modifiedTime) {
        super(url);
        mKey = id + "_" +modifiedTime;
        Log.d("GlideKey",mKey);
    }

    @Override
    public String getCacheKey() {
        return mKey;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.getCacheKey();
    }
}
```

To use it -

```
 Glide.with(context)
                .load(new GlideIdWithModifiedTime("imageUrl","someId","modifiedTime")
                .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder))
                .into(holder.courseThumbnail);
```

Comment: GlideApp.with(this)
                .load(new GlideImageUrl(g,"zuwaPic"))
                .into(simpleDraweeView);


i remove modifiedTime
I want to only work with ids and id of each  avatar will be different like it will be thier phone number

Comment: @Zuwa have you tried this -
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE) .skipMemoryCache(true)

Comment: Have you tried this
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE) .skipMemoryCache(true)

Comment: will it cache photos?
mean loaded images can work in offline mode?

Comment: No, that would make Glide load the photo each time without using the cache.  Have you found a solution?